# My php curl link rotator code needs a look over to fix

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to build a script to send visitors through which will clean up the referring domains along with a url rotator, but visiting my link isnt directing me to the site for some reason.  Im missing something in the code I believe.  Help would be lovely.

```
Visiting here, should take me to freegamesarcade.co ---> http://buyerextra.com/folder1/ref.php
```

Heres the code inside /ref.php, look correct?
    ------

```
<?php
$referrer = array(
"https://t.co /hpulBZTTIR",
"https://t.co /G1mE5AQ4c4",
"https://t.co /Bwf1Du4Sbi",
);



echo '<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />';

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle

    $ch = curl_init();


//$Url = "http://freegamesarcade.co"; 
$Url = "http://freegamesarcade.co";


$rnd= rand(0, count($referrer));                  
$ref = $referrer[$rnd];
echo $ref;

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Your referrer (you came from): https://t.co/". $ref;
'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<?=$ref;?>" />';
?>
```

Comment: Any ideas why this link doesnt take me through to freegamesarcade ? http://buyerextra.com/folder1/ref.php